# Session variables and time in Meteor: Hiding a form after it's being submitted for some time

Tags: timer, meteor, session-variables

I have a form which I would like to disable for a specific user after it's being subbmited, for an X amount of time.
I know I have to use [Timers](http://docs.meteor.com/#timers) and [Session](http://docs.meteor.com/#session) variables but as I haven't seen any examples using Timers online I don't know how to implement it.

Here's my submit event map:

```
Template.myform.events({
  'submit': function (e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitme();
    tempmarker.dragging.disable();
  }
});
```

A more specific question I have concerning Session Variables: How "safe" are they? I mean, can a user by emptying his local cache reset them?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the form in the event handler like you're doing, and then just set a timeout that re-enables it after a specific time:

```
Template.myform.events({
  'submit': function (e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitme();
    tempmarker.dragging.disable();
    // re-enable after 5s
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() { tempmarker.dragging.enable(); }, 5000);
  }
});
```

`Session` in Meteor is just an object managed by Meteor in memory on the client. It's not cached - if you reload the page, Meteor will boot up again and all your `Session` data will re-initialize. Use the session to store application state, but build your app in such a way that it can restore itself if I, for instance, mess with session values from the console.

Comment: actually this disable I do is for a map marker, but on the submit form, but I see the general idea! Would it be possible to use setTimeout server-side too, for extra security?

Comment: Sure, `setTimeout` is an "anywhere" method, but it's probably better to write the server code differently - eg measure when each new marker is added and only allow one new marker every 5 seconds from each user, or something (depending on what you want to do)

Comment: I'm just trying to avoid some user spamming the server with massive submits... trying to put some locks etc..

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos in that case, definitely verify that the forms are spaced out enough on the server - it's too easy just to change this in the client. You should never trust anything important from the client

Comment: I know, just trying to understand the tools Meteor gives me in order to do that...